# Problema ao acessar os dados de um objeto em um array de objetos

Tags: java, array

Eu tenho uma classe Loja que possui um array do tipo Produto (que possui nome, código, preço e quantidade) e preciso acessar o dado nome dos objetos desse array.

**O seguinte  código está dando problema de ponteiro na função main, porém não dá sugestões de correção:**

```
//classe main

public class ProjetoPOO1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Loja loja = new Loja();
        loja.getProdutos()[0].setNome("abacaxi");
        loja.getProdutos()[1].setNome("maça");
        loja.listarProdutos();
    }
}

//Classe Loja

public class Loja {
    private Produto[] produtos;
    private Cliente[] clientes;
    private Venda[] vendas;
    private Item[] itens;
    private static int i = 0;

    public void listarProdutos(){
        for(int j = 0; j < this.produtos[j].getNome().length() ; j++){
            System.out.print("Produto " +(j+1)); 
            System.out.println(" = " +this.produtos[j].getNome());
        }
    }

    public Produto[] getProdutos() {
        return produtos;
    }
    //restante dos getters e setters
}

// Classe Produto

public class Produto {
    private int codigo;
    private String nome;
    private float precoVenda;
    private int quantidade;
//getters e setters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando você define o array `produtos` como membro da classe `Loja` e não inicializa essa variável, o valor padrão dela é `null`. Por isso, quando você chama `loja.getProdutos()[0].setNome("abacaxi");`, está tentando pegar o elemento `0` de uma referência nula. Isso está causando um `NullPointerException`.

Crie um construtor na classe `Loja` que inicializa a variável `produtos`. Algo como:

```java
public Loja (int quantidadeProdutos) {
    this.produtos = new Produto[quantidadeProdutos]; // inicializa array
    for (int i = 0; i < quantidadeProdutos; i++) {
        this.produtos[i] = new Produto(); // inicializa cada posição do array, que null por padrão
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Funcionou :)